# Parsing the root node, to fetch the entire file structure?

Tags: python, xml, tree, xml-parsing

My *python* script reads a *XML file*, to give the *Folder Structure*.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<folderstructure>
  <folder name="Fail">
    <folder name="Cam 1">
      <folder name="Mod1">
        <folder name="2019-04-09" />
      </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="Cam 2">
      <folder name="Mod1">
        <folder name="2019-04-09" />
      </folder>
    </folder>
  </folder>
  <folder name="Pass">
    <folder name="Cam 1">
      <folder name="Mod1">
        <folder name="2019-04-09" />
      </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="Cam 2">
      <folder name="Mod1">
        <folder name="2019-04-09" />
      </folder>
    </folder>
  </folder>
</folderstructure>
```

I wrote the following script, with reference to [Fetching the path( from root node ) for all the leaf nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968311/fetching-the-path-from-root-node-for-all-the-leaf-nodes) (My previous Question):

```
def walk(e, runningPath='', flag = 1):
    name = e.attrib['name']

    if len(e)>0:
            runningPath += '/' + name
    children = [walk(c, runningPath, 0) for c in e if ((e.tag == 'folderstructure' and flag==1) or (e.tag=='folder' and flag == 0))]
    print(children)
    return {'name': name, 'children': children} if children else {'name': name, 'path': runningPath + '/' + name}
```

But the above script yields **'None'** as the **output**.

My desired output is:

```
{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'name': '2019-04-09',
                                                         'path': '/Fail/Cam '
                                                                 '1/Mod1/2019-04-09'}],
                                           'name': 'Mod1'}],
                             'name': 'Cam 1'},
                            {'children': [{'children': [{'name': '2019-04-09',
                                                         'path': '/Fail/Cam '
                                                                 '2/Mod1/2019-04-09'}],
                                           'name': 'Mod1'}],
                             'name': 'Cam 2'}],
               'name': 'Fail'},
              {'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'name': '2019-04-09',
                                                         'path': '/Pass/Cam '
                                                                 '1/Mod1/2019-04-09'}],
                                           'name': 'Mod1'}],
                             'name': 'Cam 1'},
                            {'children': [{'children': [{'name': '2019-04-09',
                                                         'path': '/Pass/Cam '
                                                                 '2/Mod1/2019-04-09'}],
                                           'name': 'Mod1'}],
                             'name': 'Cam 2'}],
               'name': 'Pass'}]
}
```

How do I go about solving this ?

Comment: Might be worth removing that bare `except` there in case you're silently swallowing errors...

Comment: @JonClements Updated the question, although it doesn't really make any difference!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns None in case of some exception. Using block `try: except` you are catching any exception, so you can't face the reason of the problem, try to remove this block from code to see the problem, or catch more specific exception.
And as I see `'folderstructure'` has no `name`, you can fix this by adding 
`<folderstructure name='some name'>` in your xml
or set default name for your `root` element.
code below seems working:

```
def walk(e, runningPath='', flag = 1):
        try:
            name = e.attrib['name']
        except KeyError:
            name = 'root'

        if len(e)>0:
            runningPath += '/' + name
        children = [walk(c, runningPath, 0) for c in e if ((e.tag == 'folderstructure' and flag==1) or (e.tag=='folder' and flag == 0))]
        print(children)
        return {'name': name, 'children': children} if children else {'name': name, 'path': runningPath + '/' + name}
```

Comment: Altering the way I use try-catch really helped. Your solution was elegant! I extended it to my use case, without having to add `name` attribute!! Thanks!!